# CSS Align 2 Divs on single line

Tags: css, html

I am trying to arrange 2 divs on one line. They are both inside a wrapper container but I am not able to style them correctly. Here is a diagram I made to better represent what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

On the left div there is text that I want to be center aligned with a Header that's located at the top of the yellow box. On the right box is an image.

Here is what I have tried...
jsfiddle.net/h8y2g/

Comment: Post some code you've tried so we have an idea what you need - best thing to do is put it into a working http://www.jsfiddle.com Fiddle

Comment: `display:inline-block`

Comment: Okay I added the code to jsfiddle for you to see. http://jsfiddle.net/h8y2g/

I want the text on the left to be aligned in the center, or top even...

Comment: I did this for fun: http://jsfiddle.net/j9tHh/2/    --- You can also just take the background color out and it would be exactly what you want..

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Close, but I want the information to be in the center of the screen? Not left.

Comment: I actually updated it to be in the center of the screen. Take a look at the jsfiddle above. Tell me if that worked for you?